# What happens if I return a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

Obviously, I would rather use `std::shared_ptr<T>` or `std::unique_ptr<T>`, but I'm dealing with some legacy code from 98/03.

My situation is:

```
auto* SomeClass::ReturnPtr( void )
{
    return this -> UniquePtrObject.get( );
};
```

What happens if I do:

```
SomeObject.ReturnPtr( ) -> SomeFunction( );
```

Does the *temporary pointer* get automatically deleted? Or am I actually causing a leak?

This makes me think of an expression like *Rvalue pointer*. Rvalue pointers don't make sense, do they?

Comment: Legacy code with return type as `auto*`?

Comment: What "temporary pointer" are you talking about? You're just returning a pointer. The behavior of that didn't change.

Comment: On top of the comments above, just a note, please do no use spaces before and after `->` or `.`

Comment: I'm writing a wrapper class for legacy code. That's why i can use unique_ptr and auto. Also, Nacho, why not?

Comment: On a side note, there is nothing wrong with the code even in 2016. It would actually be preferred over shared_ptr in many a situation (notwithstanding unneccessary type hiding with auto).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
auto* SomeClass::ReturnPtr()
{
    return this->UniquePtrObject.get();
}
```

Your pointer is valid as long as `UniquePtrObject` is (or any `reset` is done on it).

So `SomeObject.ReturnPtr()->SomeFunction()` is valid.

But following will make dangling pointer:

```
auto* createDanglingPointer()
{
    SomeClass SomeObject = MakeSomeClass();

    return SomeObject.ReturnPtr();
}
```

as someObject's lifetime ends at end of the scope.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Cheers.

Answer (score -2):

Temporary pointers are really dangerous. Whenever scope of data which it was pointing previously ends it will be freed so the pointer will become dangling and will try to access some random location for which program has no access. It may gives you wrong results, values or program may terminated with exception illegal access.